# Separating Strings by Spaces Using gets()

Tags: arrays, c, list, delimiter

Today I have a question about separating a String by white spaces using the gets() function. I have a program that takes in user input, and sorts it alphabetically. My problem is in the main function, where I take in the String. The program should stop reading user input and return the sorted linked list if a single dot at the beginning of a line OR an EOF is met. I am using gets() because it is part of the requirements of the project, however my issue is that when I use gets it simply sends the whole string into my sorting function instead of separating it by white spaces. My question is: Is there a way to separate the string captured by gets() by white spaces? Please find my implementation below as well as a sample input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//defining node structure
typedef struct node
{
    char data[255];//can store upto 255 characters
    struct node *next;
}Node;
Node *head=NULL;//initially linked list is empty
//method to insert in sorted order
void insert_dictionary_order(char *a)
{
    Node *n = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));//creating new node
    strcpy(n->data,a);//reading data
    n->next=NULL;
    Node *temp=head,*prev=NULL;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        head=n;
    }
    else
    {//inserting in right position
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(0<strcmp(temp->data,a))
                break;
            prev=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        if(prev==NULL)
        {
            n->next=head;
            head=n;
        }
        else
        {
            n->next=prev->next;
            prev->next=n;
        }
    }
}
//method to print all words in list
void print_list()
{
    Node *temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter words seperated by spaces:(. or EOF to stop):\n");

    do
    {
        char s[255];
        //scanf("%s",s);
        gets(s);
        if(strcmp(s,".")==0  || strcmp(s,"EOF")==0)
        {
            insert_dictionary_order(s);//adding to list
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            while((strcmp(s,'\0') !=0) && (strcmp(s,' ') !=0))
            {
                insert_dictionary_order(s);//adding to list
            }
        }

    }
    while(1);
    //printf("The string: %s\n", s);
    //now printing list
     print_list();
    return 0;
}
```

```
This is a sample text.
The file will be terminated by a single dot: .
The program continues processing the lines because the dot (.)
did not appear at the beginning.
. even though this line starts with a dot, it is not a single dot.
The program stops processing lines right here.
.
You won't be able to feed any more lines to the program.
```

Edit: The use of sscanf is also permitted, but not scanf

Comment: [Don't use `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html), it is fundamentally insecure. Use `fgets`. If your assignment is requiring `gets` it is either very old or not a great assignment.

Comment: !00% agree with you, and I know of the dangers of using gets(), however it is a stipulation of the assignment unfortunately. Is there any way to implement gets in the way I require? At the moment, my best attempt is the above and it still does not return the wanted output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some other stuff.

[Don't use `gets`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/getsvsfgets.html). Let's use `fgets`. Everything will be the same, just safer.

You shouldn't be using a global `head`. A pointer to the dictionary should be passed into functions. I'm not going to correct that here.

`strcpy(n->data,a)` is unsafe, you don't know how large `a` is. Instead of having a wasteful static buffer, store a `char *` and use [`strdup`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) to copy and allocate only as much memory as you need.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
n->data = strdup(word);
```

`strcmp` compares whole strings, so `strcmp(s,".")==0` will only match if `s` is exactly a single dot. `strcmp(s,'\0')` nor `strcmp(s,' ')` will not work because those are single characters, not strings. The compiler can warn you about that, but unfortunately they're off by default. Turn them on.

`strcmp(s,"EOF")==0` is looking for the string `EOF`. This is not how you detect the end of file. Instead, use `feof(stdin)` to check if you've reached the end of the file.

However, [checking for EOF is unnecessary](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html) and invites bugs. The normal `fgets` loop is something like this:

```
// Allocate a large buffer and reuse it.
char line[BUFSIZ];

// `fgets` returns NULL on error or end-of-file, which is false.
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) ) {
    // Put processing the line into a function to keep things simple.
    if( add_line(line) ) {
        // We saw a dot, exit the loop.
        break;
    }
}
```

---

> Is there a way to separate the string captured by gets() by white spaces?

With the line read we can splitting the line using [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) (STRing TOKenize). `strtok` is a funny function with its own internal state. The first time it's called it will remember what it was called with. Then you call it with `NULL` to continue finding more tokens in the string.

`strtok` works by replacing the delimiter with a null byte so you can read each token without copying it. It does modify the original string, but we don't care if `line` is modified.

```
bool add_line(char *line) {
    char *token;
    for(
      token = strtok(line, " \t\n");  // split on spaces or tabs
      token;                          // stop when there's nothing more
      token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n")   // continue splitting line
    ) {
        printf("token: %s\n", token);
        if( strcmp(token, ".") == 0 ) {
            // We saw a lone dot, stop reading.
            return true;
        }

        insert_dictionary_order(token);
    }

    // Continue reading.
    return false;
}
```

It's important to split on space as well as newline else the newline will be part of each token. This will mess up the dictionary, and also a dot at the end of a line will be `".\n"` and not match.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help it is greatly appreciated! I have just a few questions. When I try to implement the above and enter in the sample text, it does not output the file ordered alphabetically by words, rather it will output this: "The This a a be by dot: file is sample single terminated text. will". The goal of the program is to take all words leading up to the single . at the start of a line, but this one terminates just slightly earlier.

Comment: Essentially, how would I determine if the dot is the only element in an entire line?

Comment: I was able to Accomplish this by copying line to another dummy array, and checking for the value ".\n"

Comment: If you terminate on a single dot, check `strcmp(line, ".\n") == 0` in the fgets loop. Then there's no need to check inside add_line. For the sorting, it's in ASCII order. To be case insensitive, lower case the strings first.